# как изменить строку подключения (источник) в SQL агенте, отличный от того, который в SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

коллеги доброго времени суток. Я создал в Integration Services dtsx пакет , у меня всё работает норм. Я его задеплоил в SqL агент, и начинаю создавать шаги. В первом шаге, я использую источник такой же, как и в SSIS пакете. Вторым шагом, хочу изменить строку подключения, и подключиться к другой базе, развёрнутую в том же инстансе. Когда я делаю эту операцию в SSIS - всё работает прекрасно. Когда я меняю это в Sql-агенте, то вылазит вот такая ерунда
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никто не знает,  в чём может быть проблема?
P.S> выполняю задание с хабра SSIS для начинающих, часть 3

Comment: Посмотрите http://thinknook.com/ssis-the-property-parametername-contains-invalid-characters-as-an-object-name-2012-08-20/

Comment: прошу прощения, из-за того, что проект делал и дома, и на работе, наплодилось немало подключений, в которых я запутался. В итоге удалил все подключения в проекте SSIS, создал их заново, перестроил решение, заново задеплоил пакет на sql server, подключений там уже было в sql агенте столько, сколько нужно, там я и поменял без проблем подключение к разным базам. Спасибо!